# How to execute this mySQL Query?

Tags: mysql

I just need help with this mySQL question.

"Our products supplied at a higher price and it has been decided to pass this cost on to our
customers. Increase the price by 3% on all products.

Write a query that returns a list of all products, their original price, and an additional column that
contains the new (increased) prices."

Now i know how to increase the price by 3% however how am i supposed to do the second part?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Product, Price, Price * 1.03 as newprice From Tablename;
```